# Passing parameter to function in add.expr inside heatmap.2

Tags: r, line, scope, heatmap

I'm generating clustering heatmap with `heatmap.2` function (R gplots package). I'd like to add a vertical line(s) onto the image at variable location(s) using `add.expr` parameter.

For example,

```
xx=replicate(10, rnorm(10)) # some random matrix
heatmap.2(xx, trace="none",
          add.expr=abline(v=c(3.5,6.5), lwd=3))
```

This works great. The problem is it doesn't work if I pass the lines location as a variable:

```
linePosition = c(3.5,6.5)
heatmap.2(...,
          add.expr=abline(v=linePosition, lwd=3))
```

It looks like `abline` function is called from inside the heatmap.2 function and doesn't see the external variables.

Please advice what would be the best approach.

Of course, I don't want to modify any of the functions except my own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to add the two thick lines:

```
heatmap.2(xx,
       add.expr=eval( abline(v=linePosition, lwd=3)))
```

Comment: Sorry, for not upvoting and accepting your answer at that time. Somehow I overlooked it. Anyway, it looks like currently `eval` is not needed, probably after either R or heatmap.2 update.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore in R4.0.3 . I had better success with looking up the value of 'linePosition' in the calling frame, using abline(v=dynGet("linePosition",inherits=TRUE), lwd=3) . Not very pretty and probably not portable :-/

Comment: In R 3.6.3 the eval call worked fine, AND the original version by the OP now worsk. So sometime in the last 7 years, the author of gplots probably enhanced the evaluation of the arguments.